# redirect to an url with variables in post method without Javascript

Tags: php, html

I want to redirect my page to another if a condition is satisfied 
say,
samplepage1.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
if($max>$count){
//action on the same page
}
else{
//redirect to URL:index.php/samplepage2.php with the values $id & $name in POST METHOD
}
```

I need a solution so that the values must be posted to the 'samplepage2.php' through a post, but strictly not using javascript to achieve auto submission (I dont prefer the help of javascript as if user may turn it off in there browser)

Comment: Some ridiculously insignificant amount of people actually turn off JS, I think it's somewhere around 2-3% of users. Anyhow, without JS, you won't be able to do a POST redirect automatically, you'll end up presenting a "Click this button to continue: " form, which IMO is terrible.

Comment: I am trying to implement an online exam portal and the online test conducted can easily manipulated if I use js with my coding. Or it may be a good solution to restrict the whole online test - and ask to on javascript to continue...but I am limited to a situation to go with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nickb is right with his comments. If your forms or anything else handle javascript and would make a difference what your page can and cannot do, then it's pointless trying to figure out how to accomodate the $_POST.

However, one way of handling this is switch your $_POST to $_SESSION for that page.

So something like:

```
$_SESSION['form1'] = $_POST;
```

And when you reach the next page (make sure you have session_start() at the beginning of each page), you can switch it back if you really want to. Don't forget to `unset($_SESSION['form1'])` once you're done with it though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
if($max>$count){
//action on the same page
}
else{
$url = 'http://yourdomain.com/samplepage2.php';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'id='.$id);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'name='.$name);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing 2 requests?  Just do one!  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name));`

Comment: so it will redirect to 'http://yourdomain.com/samplepage2.php' if it reaches 'else{' condition right??

Comment: @RahulTS: This won't redirect you. It will just send a POST request.

Comment: so after this code if I redirect with header redirect whether I will be able to get that post values from there 'samplepage2.php'

Comment: @RahulTS: No.  Not unless you save them somewhere like the `$_SESSION`.

Comment: sorry, I dont get you I need to redirect to that page and get the values with $_POST['..'] for that what I can do

Comment: @RahulTS: This won't work for what you want, that's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: then how can I save them in session after this cURL...code -I am asking about what extra lines need to be added to achieve this on the page2

Comment: @RahulTS: On page 2, you can do `$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id']`, but I'd suggest Duniyadnd's answer of just copying the whole `$_POST` array to `$_SESSION`, then redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

if `curl` is enabled on your server than you can use curl to send `POST` data to another form,

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "index.php/samplepage2.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'id' => 'value of id',
    'name' => 'value of name'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: He wants to redirect to the page (like if you were to POST a form on an HTML page).  This will not redirect you.